# Hibernate: Wrong column type: accountBalance, expected: numeric(19,2)?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2008

I'm getting the following error.

> Wrong column type: accountBalance, expected: numeric(19,2).

I tried adding the `columnDefinition="smallmoney"`

But didn't work.

I can change it to Integer but I'm little bit cautious after reading this mapping.. http://jtds.sourceforge.net/typemap.html

Any Ideas what to do..I'm using MSSQL server in the backend..

Changed it to `Integer` now its saying

> Wrong column type: accountBalance, expected: int

My current annotation Definition is like this.

```
@Column(name = "AccountBalance",columnDefinition="smallmoney", nullable = false, precision = 10)
 private BigDecimal accountBalance;
```

Comment: What type is the column in the database?

Comment: `smallmoney` is the data type of column

Comment: smallmoney will fit nicely into a decimal, but you might have problems as decimal can easily overflow smallmoney. I'd use decimal for the class, and decimal(18, 3) for the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was doing was correct, I was getting that error because I had kept

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate //validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
```

After changing This value to

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update  // update the schema.
```

everything works fine..

but not sure about the actual cause...